# как читать строку через scanf?

Tags: c, строки, ввод

объявляю строку через указатель (задание такое), надо ее прочитать через scanf, оно не работает, подскажите пожалуйста

```
int main(){
    char *s;
    scanf("%s", &s);
    printf("%s", s);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо выделить память, куда читать...

```
char * s = malloc(1024); // Или сколько вам надо
scanf("%s",s);      // Чтение ОДНОГО СЛОВА
scanf("%[^\n]",s);  // Чтение строки до конца (символа новой строки)
```

Comment: огромное спасибо, очень долго мучался

Comment: а если я не знаю, какой длины строка, сколько мне памяти выделять?

Comment: Или заведомо много, или читать посимвольно, или выделять память и читать с помощью `scanf_s` и смотреть, заполнился ли буфер...