# Почему то не корректно работает

Tags: c

Объясните мне пожалуйста, почему не переворачивает фразу корректно? Вроде работает но не так.

Sample Input:
sI ur.redoCgnuoY a doog ?etis

Sample Output:
Is YoungCoder.ru a good site?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main()
{
  char str[100];
  fgets(str, 100, stdin);
  fflush(stdin);
  char *pch=strtok(str, " ");
  
  
  
  while (pch != NULL) //пока есть лексемы
  {
      int n=strlen(pch);
    for (int i=n; i>0; i--) {
      printf("%c", pch[i]);
    }   
      pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
  }    
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индексация букв в строке 0 .. n-1 и в конце нулевой байт как признак конца строки и выглядит так :

```
"abc"  
strlen ( "abc" ) = 3

[0] : 'a'
[1] : 'b'
[2] : 'c'
[3] : '\00'
```

Вы печатаете начиная со знака конца строки и не захватываете первую букву.

```
for (int i=n; i>0; i--)
```

Переделываем цикл и не забываем печатать разделитель (пробел).

```
for (int i=n-1; i>=0; i--) {
  printf("%c", pch[i]);
}   
fputs(" ",stdout);
```

---

Функция `fgets` записывает также знак конца строки `'\n'`. Чтобы не было с ним проблем, его можно стереть или вместо `fgets` использовать `scanf`.

```
size_t n = strlen(str);
if(str[n-1] == '\n')
  str[n-1] = '\00';
```

или

```
scanf("%99[^\n]",str);
```

Comment: Точно! спасибо.

Comment: Сейчас вывел как надо, только почему то последнее слово на новую строку перевел. Не понял почему? Вот как вышло: Is YoungCoder.ru a good (а слово site на новой строке)
site?

Comment: функция `fgets` записывает в строку всё включая знак переноса строки `'\n'`. Можете изменить на другу функцию чтения строки, например `scanf("%99s",str);`

Comment: Точно. Хех, жаль я начал изучать программирование только в 36:( А что означает 99 в сканф? сканировать 99 символов?

Comment: лимит записи, чтобы не портить память, записывая большую строку.

Comment: А как вернуть строку вверх ? ну то есть символ обратный \n?

Comment: Хочу сделать так if (pch[i]=='\n')
        printf("(вот сюда что вставить что бы он вверх вернулся и продолжил печатать в одну строку");

Comment: это всё от системы зависит. нестандарт. лучше не переходить на новую строку

Comment: Я вставил scanf("%99s",str); вместо fgets(str, 100, stdin); но тогда он у меня только первое слово sl из всей фразы записывает.

Comment: точно. измените отсюда https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1344934/288358

Comment: Спасибо Вам за помощь!